# CollapsingToolbarLayout with tablayout & image as collapsing with sticky toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I want to achieve view similar to below images

[image: Initial view that I need in my app]

[image: After user start scrolling view should look like below image]

Below are the screens that I have achieved through design support library in android

[image: View i created with mentioned xml]
[image: When i scroll is hides the tablayout which is not good.]

Please see  my layout file below

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/imageburger"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />




                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable" />




            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

please check the above xml and let me know what I am doing wrong??

Comment: check this link. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: Not use full for the scenario ,Already tried that.

Comment: You don't need the extra FrameLayout. Just add the FAB in the CoordinatorLayout and use it's anchor attributes for the FAB

Comment: bro..did you get any solution.Please suggest.

Comment: @Zafar Alam , No I didnt find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Paul Burke gists, it may be solve your problem,

https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

Comment: I want to show toolbar and tab layout both when collapse toolbar collapse it self. SO the given links  is not about issue I am talking .

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by this example https://github.com/vitovalov/TabbedCoordinatorLayout.

My code looks like this now:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Trans">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
        <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Let me try this & get back to you , if it is working or not , Thanks for the reply.

Comment: hello, any solution you found? i also need to implement the same. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can try soucecode ex

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vUserProfileRoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                    android:paddingRight="24dp"
                    android:paddingTop="60dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clipChildren="false">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivUserProfilePhoto"
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="70dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/vdo"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/vUserDetails"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/vUserStats"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="1167"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="videos"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="396"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="followers"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="485"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Student"
                                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="218dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                >

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:scaleType="center"
                                    android:background="@drawable/image_btn_follow_src"
                                    />

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/btn_report"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/report_btn"
                                    />


                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>



                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="I stuck in problem I have one project which uses JNI libs but when I use in another project it throws error unable to find jni"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />


                </LinearLayout>




                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvUserProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/new_conn"
                    layout="@layout/custom_profile_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />






            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp">

                <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
                    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
                    app:primaryColor="@color/white"
                    app:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:accentColor="@color/gray"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />

                <!--<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tabHost"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="48dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="15dp"-->
                <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"-->
                <!--app:tabBackground="@color/white"-->
                <!--app:tabGravity="center"-->
                <!--app:tabMode="scrollable"-->
                <!--app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"-->
                <!--app:tabTextColor="@color/gray" />-->


            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you have to download ex : https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview

https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView